# Obj-c, UIActivityIndicatorView not work while IBAction click

Tags: objective-c

I have a code that upload image to my server, I put an UIActivityIndicatorView while the image is uploading to the server.
the its the UIActivityIndicatorView does not appear until the end of the code, only after the image has been uploaded then the UIActivityIndicatorView appears.

this is the code:

```
- (IBAction)sendTHE:(id)sender {

    _sendTHE.enabled = NO;
    LodingactivityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [LodingactivityIndicator startAnimating];

    if ([_textmsg.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *userExists = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error:" message:@"Please write some message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [userExists show];
        _sendTHE.enabled = YES;
    }
    else {

        NSString *URLString;
        NSData *storeData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView.image, 90);
        if (_imageView.image==NULL)
        {    URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://37.142.62.22/the/sendmsg.php?f=ns&t=%@&sn=%@&re=%@", _textmsg.text,_userid,_reciverid];
        }
        else if (_imageView.image!=NULL)
        {    URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://37.142.62.22/the/sendmsg.php?f=fs&t=%@&sn=%@&re=%@", _textmsg.text,_userid,_reciverid];
        }
        NSMutableURLRequest *request  = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", @"the"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:storeData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [LodingactivityIndicator stopAnimating];


        //NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
        //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showfriends" sender:self];

    }


}
```

the UIActivityIndicatorView start after the NSURLConnection perform the request.
how can I display the UIActivityIndicatorView while the request is perform ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing the request synchronously on the main thread. This means your `sendTHE:` method doesn't return (and all views are disabled) until the request returns.

You have a few options.

You could do your request synchronously on a different thread besides the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    /* Do your networking */ 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        /* Update your UI with the result */

    });
});
```

You could use `[NSURLConnection +sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`.

You could use a library like AFNetworking that handles this all for you.

Remember:

- Don't block the main thread with time-consuming network and disk operations
- Always update your UI on the main thread